# Javascript does not execute with ClientScriptManager in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a composite control with some buttons. This is the code of a button.
The  javascript called is never executed.
But if I comment the Response.Redirect line, the javascript called by server does execute.
Why this behavior?. I know that I can add an 'OnClick' attribute with an 'alert' in the button, but my interest here is to understand the logic of javascript when is called from sever side. Any help will be appreciated.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "AlertMsgPopup"))
    {
        String cstext1 = "alert('Some message');";
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AlertMsgPopup", cstext1, true);
    }

    SomeMethod();  
    Page.Response.Redirect(SomePage);
}
```

Comment: you want to `alert` and redirect to another page and also expect that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the code in your `Delete_Click` method is executing on the server-side of things.  That means that control of the program is at the server.  Since JavaScript runs at the client (in their browser), this won't actually execute yet.

The fact that you do a `Response.Redirect` at the server negates the possibility of that script running entirely - you are stopping the execution of the current request, and performing a new one (for "SomePage").  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Calling [Redirect
>   (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>   is equivalent to calling [Redirect (String,
>   Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>   with the second parameter set to true.